# Got error: Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto), : Viewport has zero dimension(s)

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to do a cnetplot on my DE genes and am seeing this error. I read in another post, that I need to increase my size. But how do I do that?

```
cnetplot(DE.BP, font.size = 16,
           showCategory = 10,
           categorySize="p.adjust",
           colorEdge = TRUE,
           shadowtext="none")
```

**Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  :
Viewport has zero dimension(s)**

I was expecting a plot